# How to Install Mondrian?

Tags: mondrian

I am trying to install Mondrian on OS X EL Capitan. The file downloaded from the official Mondrian website is a .jar file whereas the official document talks about the .war file.

Can anybody guide me on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

The .war project was discontinued but check the following reference:

http://rpbouman.blogspot.mx/2016/03/need-mondrian-war-checkout-xmondrian.html